# Lucene.Net Keyword based case insensitive query?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I need to make a Lucene exact case insensitive keyword match query.

I tried using KeywordAnalyzer but it's case sensitive ...

Sample :

Keyword : "Windows Server 2003" => Got Results

Keyword : "windows server 2003" => No results ...

Another sample (multi keywords) :

Keywords : "ASP.NET, SQL Server" => Got results

Keywords : "asp.net, sql server" => No results

Answer (score 1):

I never used lucene, but from what I found on google, StopAnalyzer and SimpleAnalyzer seem to use a LowerCaseFilter.
As a last resort, you can build a custom analyzer, inheriting from the abstract base class "Analyzer".

Much of what I found you can read on this page: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/lucene_analysis.aspx, in which you can even find a sample app that can help you :)